# Drupal Views Custom Table on Multisite

Tags: 7, views, multi-sites

I have installed a drupal7 multisite.

Views module is present in main site (sites/all/modules/contrib)

Custom module is present in site1 (sites/site1/modules/custom)

In custom module (site1), I have written code for integration of a database table to Views (using hook_views_data).

But in site1 views, this table is not being listed. What might be the problem ?

Basically I want views module to be enabled in all sites. A custom database table to be integrated to views in a particular site (say site1). Is there any method to achieve this ?

Note : The custom module works fine on a non multisite instance.